# Generate all possible permutations of incomplete distinct objects in R

Tags: r, lapply

Suppose `v=c(-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1)` and I want to generate all the permutations. There are `9!/(3!3!3!)=1680`

Currently, I'm using the following line to get that, but it is not very efficient.

```
unique(replicate(100000, sample(v), simplify=FALSE))
```

This is one possible case. I want to generalize this. Suppose `n` objects consist of `k` distinct objects `a1,a2,...,ak` with repetition numbers `n1,n2,...,nk (n1+n2+...+nk=n)`respectivly. Then `n!/(n1!n2!...nk!)`

How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `iterpc` package

```
library(iterpc)
getall(iterpc(table(v), ordered = TRUE))
```

It is at least 5000x faster than the `combinat::permn` approach of ds440.

```
> system.time(unique(combinat::permn(v)))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.861   0.037   4.902 
> system.time(getall(iterpc(table(v), ordered = TRUE)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.000   0.001
```

and 10x faster than sirallen approach.

```
> microbenchmark(getall(iterpc(table(v), ordered = TRUE)), sirallen())
Unit: microseconds
                                     expr      min       lq      mean    median
 getall(iterpc(table(v), ordered = TRUE))  583.512  605.699  804.0107  748.9305
                               sirallen() 5784.122 7571.282 8777.4111 8256.1035
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
u  = list(unique(v))
Pv = expand.grid(rep(u,9))
Pv = Pv[rowSums(Pv==-1)==3 & rowSums(Pv==0)==3,]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a permutations function to generate all possibilities then filter.  If you need a guarantee of all possibilities this has advantages over the sample method in your question however it can 'crash' if you have a long vector.

```
v=c(-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
unique(combinat::permn(v))
```

This method is much less quick than @sirallen's approach.  A generalization of that approach might be:

```
u  <- unique(v)
Pv <- expand.grid(rep(list(u),length(v)))
for(i in seq_along(u)) {
Pv <- Pv[rowSums(Pv==u[i])==sum(u[i]==v),]
}
dim(Pv)
```